# Showing that a recursive sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to show that the sequence $x_n$ defined as :

$x_0=0 , x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1/4 $ is bounded. Not sure how to approach this, some hints would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please indicate what you have done so far and where you are stuck. This will better help others tailor an answer to your particular background and skill level. It also will encourage others to help you as they can see you are committed to the question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would prove that $x_n<\frac{1}{2}$. Proof by induction.

$x_0=0<\frac{1}{2}$

If $x_n<\frac{1}{2}$ then $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1/4<(\frac{1}{2})^2+1/4=\frac{1}{2}$.

So, $x_n<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is not there another way? It kind of follows by knowing the limit in the first place.

Comment: @LostUser you could determine the bound $M$ by requiring $M^2 + \frac 14 \le M$, so that $x_n < M$ implies $x_{n+1}^2 + \frac 14 < M$. It turns out that $M = \frac 12$ is the only number that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a solution such that $x_n=x_{n+1}$.  This will be the limit, meaning that once we reach $x_n$, then we can not exceed it any further.$$x_n=x_{n+1}=x_n^2+\frac14$$$$x_n=x_n^2+\frac14$$$$0=x_n^2-x_n+\frac14$$$$x_n=\frac12,-\frac32$$By obvious reasoning, we can see that $x_n\ne-\frac32$ and get the sole solution:$$x_n=\frac12$$

Comment: Sir, is such solution always exists? I mean solution such that $x_n=x_{n+1}$ ? For example: sequence defined by $a_n=1/n$ is bounded but $a_{n+1}≠a_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So sir I think this method  do not work in general. Is this method always works for sequences which are recursively defined?

Comment: That sequence is not recursively defined i.e. $a_{n+1}$  is not written in terms of $a_n$. And if no such solution exists for $x=f(x)$ with continuous $f$, then the sequence given by $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ will not converge.